# how to test django fixture json file

Tags: django, django-testing, django-tests, django-fixtures, django-manage.py

I has a script that will generate a JSON file (let me call it `data.json`) that for my django application, usually I can test it by running command

`python manage.py testserver data.json`

However, I would like to run this thing in unit tests rather than run this through shell (because it would start a server and never return back to the shell). I don't need to run any tests that depends on this fixture. I only want to make sure that the fixture generated can be loaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django's own `TestCase` supports automatically setting up and tearing down fixtures via the class level [`fixtures`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TransactionTestCase.fixtures) attribute. e.g.

```
from django.test import TestCase

class MyTest(TestCase):

    # Must live in <your_app>/fixtures/data.json
    fixtures = ['data.json']

    def test_something(self):
        # When this runs, data.json will already have been loaded
        ...
```

However, since you just want to check that the fixture can be loaded rather than using it as part of the test, then you could just invoke the `loaddata` command somewhere in your test code.

e.g.

```
from django.core.management import call_command

call_command('loaddata', '/path/to/data.json')
```

Comment: Well, that means the fixture will be actually loaded into real database, which I would like to avoid.

Comment: @HsiaoYi so you wish to load it into a different database? You have a specific database configured for that?

Comment: I would like to have that be loaded into a test database, but would not start a test server. One thing I am thinking right now is to use the fundamental mechanism without running the server (https://github.com/django/django/blob/fbc7e4138921d0fbee823ce6ea9774de66d27e47/django/core/management/commands/testserver.py#L30-L37), but I am afraid I miss something.

Comment: If your unit test extends Django's `TestCase`, then this would all happen for you when you run your test. Django would insert the fixture data into the test database before the test starts.

Comment: Do you mean I should `call_command('loaddata', ...)` inside a unit test that extends `TransactionTestCase` ?

Comment: Well you wouldn't have to call `loaddata` at all. You could set the `fixtures` attribute to `['data.json']` and then let Django automatically load the data into the test database before the test runs. The `data.json` file would need to be placed in a folder called `fixtures` inside your app. I've added an example to the answer.

Comment: You should probably also use `django.test.TestCase` which inherits from `TransactionTestCase` (as shown in the example)

Answer (score 0):

Django management commands can be run in your code using the [call_commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/django-admin/#running-management-commands-from-your-code).

```
from django.core.management import call_command
from django.core.management.commands import testserver

call_command('testserver', 'data.json')
```

Comment: However, it looks like it will not return back to the shell.